# svg rectangles overlapping stroke width

Tags: html, svg

For a hobby project (nonogram) I am trying to make a grid using svg rectangles.
On every 5th rows and column the border stroke width is much higher than the normal rectangles.

On the internet I found something about stroke-dashoffset and stroke-dasharray but you can not change the thickness on one side.
So I thought why not creating multiple rectangles overlapping each other so the border thickness can overlap the other rectangle, but unfortunately that is not working. Perhaps I have made a mistake or it is not possible what I want to create.

The first 5 svg elements are the one for the borders and all the other elements are the individual rectangles.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="1000" height="1000">            
    <rect x=10 y=10 width=200 height=200 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:4 "/>
    <rect x=10 y=10 width=100 height=100 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:4 "/>
    <rect x=10 y=110 width=100 height=100 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:4 "/>
    <rect x=110 y=110 width=100 height=100 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:4 "/>
    <rect x=110 y=10 width=100 height=100 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:4 "/>
    <rect x=10 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=30 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=50 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=70 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=90 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=110 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=130 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=150 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=170 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=190 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=10 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=30 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=50 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=70 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=90 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=110 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=130 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=150 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=170 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=190 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=10 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=30 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=50 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=70 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=90 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=110 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=130 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=150 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=170 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=190 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=10 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=30 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=50 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=70 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=90 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=110 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=130 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=150 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=170 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=190 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=10 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                    
    <rect x=30 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                    
    <rect x=50 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                    
    <rect x=70 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                    
    <rect x=90 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                    
    <rect x=110 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=130 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=150 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=170 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=190 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=10 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=30 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=50 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=70 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=90 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=110 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=130 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=150 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=170 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=190 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=10 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=30 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=50 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=70 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=90 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=110 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=130 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=150 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=170 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=190 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=10 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=30 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=50 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=70 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=90 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=110 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=130 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=150 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=170 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=190 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=10 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=30 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=50 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=70 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=90 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=110 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=130 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=150 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=170 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=190 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=10 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=30 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=50 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=70 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=90 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=110 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=130 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=150 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=170 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=190 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just antialiasing. You can turn it off via shape rendering e.g. shape-rendering: crispEdges;

It would also be less markup if you

- set common styles on a parent `<g>` element
- redid the whole thing using a pattern (you'd only need to draw one square and repeat it for the inside then draw the outline as a big rect.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="1000" height="1000" shape-rendering="crispEdges">            
    <rect x=10 y=10 width=200 height=200 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:4 "/>
    <rect x=10 y=10 width=100 height=100 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:4 "/>
    <rect x=10 y=110 width=100 height=100 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:4 "/>
    <rect x=110 y=110 width=100 height=100 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:4 "/>
    <rect x=110 y=10 width=100 height=100 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:4 "/>
    <rect x=10 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=30 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=50 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=70 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=90 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=110 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=130 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=150 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=170 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=190 y=10 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=10 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=30 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=50 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=70 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=90 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=110 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=130 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=150 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=170 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=190 y=30 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=10 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=30 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=50 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=70 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=90 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=110 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=130 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=150 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=170 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=190 y=50 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>               
    <rect x=10 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=30 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=50 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=70 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=90 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                
    <rect x=110 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=130 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=150 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
    <rect x=170 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=190 y=70 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=10 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                    
    <rect x=30 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                    
    <rect x=50 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                    
    <rect x=70 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                    
    <rect x=90 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                    
    <rect x=110 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=130 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=150 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=170 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=190 y=90 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=10 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=30 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=50 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=70 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=90 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=110 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=130 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=150 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=170 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=190 y=110 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=10 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=30 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=50 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=70 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=90 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=110 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=130 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=150 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=170 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=190 y=130 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=10 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=30 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=50 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=70 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=90 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=110 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=130 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=150 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=170 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=190 y=150 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=10 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=30 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=50 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=70 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=90 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=110 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=130 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=150 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=170 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=190 y=170 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=10 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=30 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=50 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=70 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=90 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                   
    <rect x=110 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=130 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=150 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=170 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>                  
    <rect x=190 y=190 width=20 height=20 style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1 "/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will certainly looking at the markup indeed much better than how I do it right now. But still the crispEdges is not the solution. I still don't get the stroke thickness at the 5x5 rectangles, or must I first to the svg grouping stuff.